# How to generate a text file based on a UML diagram using NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, uml

I want to create a custom XML file based on a UML model using NetBeans.
 Does anyone have an idea to do this?
Actually, I want to draw a model in NetBeans and use it to generate code.

Comment: A little more detail would help. A text file (that is the same all the time or different) that looks like uml or copies a uml file and converts to text while using a netbeans program(possible button click) producing a opened notepad or other text file or held within a Jframe etc display.

Comment: @mic84 Actually, I want to draw a model in NetBeans and use it to generate code.